# Assignment of function variables in Python

Tags: python

I want to create a function, which looks like the following:

```
def function(ticker,A,B):
    dataframe = df['string']
    return dataframe
```

The dataframe df should get the Strings like '20' oder '10' so that its name looks like, e.g. df_20_10.

```
def function(ticker,A,B):
        dataframe = df_A_B['string']
        return dataframe
```

-> does not work

Can anybody help me, please?

Comment: Variable names shouldn't be data. You should probably create a dictionary or list of your dataframes, which you can index with `A` and `B` to get the particular one you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using `locals()` or `globals()`, like this:

```
dataframe = locals()['df_{}_{}'.format(A, B)]['string']
```

Shorter version (in Python 3.6+):

```
dataframe = locals()[f'df_{A}_{B}']['string']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def function (ticker,A,B):
    dataframe = eval("df_"+A+"_"+B)["string"]
    return dataframe
```

I'm not sure if this is what you want though. Sorry if it's not.